# Add a second Wordpress Loop that displays latest posts in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, archive, sidebar

I am creating my own Theme, but have only basic knowledge of PHP. I've been looking for a way to do this online but cannot seem to come across it.

**This is the url of my development server:** http://dev.mindthegaspar.com/nuevanacion/

I want to have a secondary loop in every page on the sidebar that displays all the latests posts. It is straightforward on the main **Index.php** file.

I'm not sure where yo begin to get it working on the **Single.php** file. I understand he concept of the WordPress loop, and why it won't work inside a Category of Post page, but is there a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked into using the sidebar widgets? I don't know if what you ask has already been made but wordpress has many thousands of plugins. It is likely that someone out there has already built this widget for you.

Comment: i've googled for stuff like that but nothing. There are some for displaying posts from specific categories. I also figured someone had made a loop like the one I want but nothing really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your sidebar:

```
$today = getdate();
$sidebarquery = new WP_Query( 'year=' . $today["year"] . '&monthnum=' . $today["mon"] . '&day=' . $today["mday"] );

while($sidebarquery->have_posts()) {
   $sidebarquery->the_post();
   echo '<li>' .  the_permalink(); . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just so I'm clear, three questions: **1. The first** two lines create a new query for posts beginning from $today (variable) and older, the loop then goes through the posts gathered by WP_Query in $sidebarquery? **2. I can** add elements inside the loop like regular? **3. The sidebar** code goes first in my markup, so this is the first loop that runs, do I have to run a WP_Query reset before the main loop?  Thanks!!

Comment: no prob. This only retrieves posts for today. You can add more parameters for a range of dates as well. If you have a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query you'll find all the possible parameters. You can create different loops using a different variable name but its good practice to reset afterwards if not needed. Im not sure what you mean by elements? All the loop functions will work the same in your loop!

Comment: thanks! I will look into it, with that I'm fairly sure I can figure it out on my own :)

Comment: yes, of course! I didn't have the chance to test it out until now. I just got it working :)